# Jquery Validation: allow only alphabets and spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My validation accepts only alphabets. I want allow spaces as well.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("alpha", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/);
});
```

What change needs to be done here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Instead of the below regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Use this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

This will also take the space.

Answer (score 3):

Just leave a space or use `\s` in your regex:

```
$.validator.addMethod("alpha", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/);
    // --                                    or leave a space here ^^
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonlys", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(value);
}, "Letters only please");
```

Use pattern: `/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/`

Answer (score 2):

Your validation is proper. You just need to change regex  `/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/`

```
$.validator.addMethod("alpha", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**

> I have tried above but space was an issue in above given regex 
>   /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/ and /^[a-zA-Z]+$/. The Below worked for me:

**

```
  $('.name-val').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
    var strigChar = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(strigChar)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use these pattern for validation.

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
if(!pattern.test(name) && name !=''){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's great that you've offered an answer here, but I don't think it's correct - the question is asking for a regex that validates for alphabetic characters and spaces, yours doesn't seem to include spaces.

Comment: Please share some explanation for that code such that others can learn from it

Comment: This validation is used for only alphabetical and space allow for specific fields. +$ allows to enter space for any field.