# Need help in jQuery form validation in php page

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate plugin for validations. Now I want textbox is suppose to accept only alphabets in country title section. How to do it?

Following is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="post" name="register-form" id="register-form" >
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Country Code</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="countrycode" id="countrycode">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Country Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control round-input" name="countryname" id="countryname">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Country ISD Code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="countryisdcode" id="countryisdcode">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Descrition</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <textarea name="" class="form-control" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>

(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#register-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    countrycode: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength:2,
                            integer:false
                                 },
                    countryname: "required",

                 /*  countryisdcode:
                            {  required :true,
                               integer:true,
                               minlength: 2
                            },*/

                      },
                messages: {
                    countrycode: {
                     required:"Please enter Countrycode",
                     minlength:"Minimum length is 2",
                     integer:"Please enter only "
                     },
                    countryname: "Please enter CountryName",
                  /*  countryisdcode:  {
                            required :"Please enter CountryISDcode",
                            integer:"Please enter Only numbers",
                            minlength:"minimum length is 2"
                                     }, */

                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);

</script>
```

Comment: I see on console `JQuery is not defined.`, did you check for errors in console ?

Comment: no..i didn't check but validations for first two fields are working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Validation: allow only alphabets and spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777711/jquery-validation-allow-only-alphabets-and-spaces)

Comment: Review the very simple example posted on the [SO Tag Wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) to see that the code from the JQUERY4U tutorial is utterly convoluted and ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a custom method with a regex

```
$.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
  return regexpr.test(value);
}, "Letters only");
```

And then :

```
$("#register-form").validate({
  rules: {
    countrycode: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2,
      integer: false
    },
    countryname: {
      required: true ,
      regx: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/
    }
  }
});
```

Change the regexp if this one doesn't fit your needs.